# cant check "Allow Unsafe code" in my project option

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, compilation, unsafe

I followed forums to activate "unsafe code" in my visual studio 2015 project.
It's a visual studio xamarin project.

I search in project properties and saw the checkbox "Allow unsafe code". but cant check it, it is disable.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: What type of Xamarin project is it?

Comment: It's a portable xamarin.forms project

Comment: anyone have an idea about this ? is it possible that option is not allowed on community version of visual studio 2015 ?

Comment: Try adding `<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>` directly to your `.csproj` within the debug and release `PropertyGroup`s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsafe code won't compile on Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295228/unsafe-code-wont-compile-on-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same with a PCL-project.
I removed Silverlight from the targets, because I don't need it.
This enabled checkbox "Allow unsafe code"